# DAO слой, обработка поля List<> обьекта в JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

Делаю ДАО слой, есть классы Student, Teacher, Audience, Group и Lecture. Класс Group содержит лист обьектов Student, а класс Lecture содержит все эти классы, причем группы содержит поле List.

```
public class Lecture {
    private String lectureName;
    private Audience audience;
    private Teacher teacher;
    private List<Group> groups;
    private Date date;
}
```

Если в ДАО слое обработку классов Teacher, Student, Audience сделал без проблем, то как сделать ДАО класс для Lecture, как обрабатывать поле групп?
P.S. в классе Lecture может содержать как одна группа так и несколько.

Comment: Так а в чем вопрос то? Что мешает обработать "поле групп" так же как и Teacher, Student, Audience?

Comment: Я так понимаю обрабатывать с помощью нескольких statement в одной транзакции?

Comment: Вы DAO делаете для Lecture? Если да, то в одной транзакции.